# Microsoft Dynamics CRM - password hashing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, password-hash, hashalgorithm

I work at a University and our application for admissions is a product that is built on top of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0.  (The application is called 'Recruiter'.)

There is a table with usernames and hashed passwords.  I would like to write an app (in Ruby on Rails) that queries the username and hashed password to validate a login.

Unfortunately, I do not know how the hashed password is generated.  It appears to be a Base64-encoded MD5 checksum.

I have read elsewhere that the hashed password is generated using a combination of:

1. the plaintext password
2. the primary key of the record (a UUID string, not an integer)
3. the database server name

I have tried variations of this to create a hashed password that matches the record in the database, but I cannot get this to work.

Can anyone tell me how to generate a matching hashed password from a plaintext password?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using IFD authentication? What table contains user's login information?

Comment: @IvanBenko I don't know if I am using IFD authentication.  The table name with user login data is based on the database tables that 'Recruiter' adds on top of MS Dynamics CRM.  The table name is `Datatel_core_externaluserauthenticationExtensionBase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a customization based on the capabilities of Dynamics CRM. It looks like Dynamics CRM is used as a framework for this. You have to contact the original creator of this application.

Comment: I have contacted creator of the application and am still waiting for a response.